# Is it possible to Edit and Continue in Visual Studio 2010 while debugging an MVC 4 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have enabled Edit and Continue in Tools->Options->Debugging->Edit&Continue
However, I still have the "Changes are not allowed" message if I try to modify the code.
Is there something to do to enable E+C ?

Comment: E+C isn't supported on x64 processes. Is your project configured to use x64?

Comment: Did you enable it on the project?  Project -> Properties -> Web -> Enable Edit and Continue

Comment: @vcsjones: Until VS2013.

Comment: @SLaks, yes, the 4.5.1 framework introduces this.

Comment: I didn't know I had to enable it in the project properties as well. Now it works, thank you! You should probably change your comment into an answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

If your process is 32-bit it allows, settings matter.

However, if your process is 64-bit, you are not allowed to edit and continue, no matter what your settings are.

Comment: 64 bit support Now available for 2013. [check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)